# Chartjs color the background of chart after specific values with dark grey color

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I am new to ChartJS and due to server constraints I am using ChartJS 2.9.4 using cdnjs and I want to color the background of line chart from

1. 60-80 ==> light grey with background text in right side as Significant with dotted lines
2. 80-100 ==> dark grey with background text in right side as Severe

Currently it is like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWWX6.png)

And the requirement is this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttnGS.png)

Below is the implemented code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
      var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "line",
        data: {
          labels: [
            "",
            "Working Memory",
            "Inhibitory Control",
            "Cognitive Flexibility",
            "High Order EF",
            "",
          ],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Competence score in Percent",
              data: [null, 80, 65, 90, 75],
              borderColor: ["#000", "#ffdb14", "#ff0000", "#38b7fe", "#8866f9"],
              backgroundColor: [
                "#000",
                "#ffdb14",
                "#ff0000",
                "#38b7fe",
                "#8866f9",
              ],
              fill: false,
              pointRadius: 16,
              pointHoverRadius: 8,
              pointBackgroundColor: [
                "#000",
                "#ffdb14",
                "#ff0000",
                "#38b7fe",
                "#8866f9",
              ],
              lineTension: 0,
              borderColor: "#000",
              borderWidth: 2,
            },
          ],
        },
        options: {
          responsive: true,
          scales: {
            xAxes: [
              {
                scaleLabel: {
                  display: true,
                  labelString: "Subtests",
                  fontSize: 24,
                },
                ticks: {
                  fontSize: 24,
                },
              },
            ],
            yAxes: [
              {
                scaleLabel: {
                  display: true,
                  labelString: "Competence score in Percent",
                  fontSize: 24,
                },
                ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true,
                  min: 0,
                  max: 100,
                  stepSize: 25,
                  fontSize: 24,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
          legend: {
            display: false,
          },
        },
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go is to try using [`chartjs-plugin-annotation`](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/)
whose [version 0.5.7](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/0.5.7/) should work with
chart.js version 2.x

You'd use a box annotation and a text annotation for
each band.

If your restrictions don't even allow to use that,
and since your drawings are quite specific, you can
implement yourself a plugin to draw the bands.

The plugin should implement the method
[beforeDraw](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api), and get
hold of the drawing context and the axes through it `chart`
first argument. Those would very simply allow you
to draw anywhere on the canvas before the chart
is drawn:

```js
plugins:[{
    beforeDraw(chart){
        const ctx = chart.ctx,
            xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'],
            xMin = xAxis.left,
            xMax = xAxis.right,
            yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'],
            y100 = yAxis.getPixelForValue(100),
            y80 = yAxis.getPixelForValue(80),
            y60 = yAxis.getPixelForValue(60);
    
        // draw with these ...........
    }
}]
```

Here's a snippet implementing a possible solution:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    plugins:[{
        beforeDraw(chart){
            const ctx = chart.ctx,
                xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'],
                xMin = xAxis.left,
                xMax = xAxis.right,
                yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'],
                y100 = yAxis.getPixelForValue(100),
                y80 = yAxis.getPixelForValue(80),
                y60 = yAxis.getPixelForValue(60);
            
            for(var [yMin, yMax, color, text] of
                [[y60, y80, 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.8)', 'Significant'],
                    [y80, y100, 'rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.8)', 'Severe']]){
                ctx.fillStyle = color;
                ctx.fillRect(xMin, yMin, xMax-xMin, yMax-yMin);
                ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)';
                ctx.textAlign = 'right';
                ctx.font = Math.round(Math.min((yMax-yMin)/3, 48))+'px serif';
                ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
                ctx.fillText(text, xMax-10,(yMax+yMin)/2)
                ctx.strokeText(text, xMax-10,(yMax+yMin)/2)
            }
        }
    }],
    data: {
        labels: [
            "",
            "Working Memory",
            "Inhibitory Control",
            "Cognitive Flexibility",
            "High Order EF",
            "",
        ],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "Competence score in Percent",
                data: [null, 80, 65, 90, 75],
                borderColor: ["#000", "#ffdb14", "#ff0000", "#38b7fe", "#8866f9"],
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#000",
                    "#ffdb14",
                    "#ff0000",
                    "#38b7fe",
                    "#8866f9",
                ],
                fill: false,
                pointRadius: 16,
                pointHoverRadius: 8,
                pointBackgroundColor: [
                    "#000",
                    "#ffdb14",
                    "#ff0000",
                    "#38b7fe",
                    "#8866f9",
                ],
                lineTension: 0,
                borderColor: "#000",
                borderWidth: 2,
            },
        ],
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            xAxes: [
                {
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: "Subtests",
                        fontSize: 24,
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        fontSize: 24,
                    },
                },
            ],
            yAxes: [
                {
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: "Competence score in Percent",
                        fontSize: 24,
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        min: 0,
                        max: 100,
                        stepSize: 25,
                        fontSize: 24,
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
        legend: {
            display: false,
        },
    },
});
```

```html
<canvas id="lineChart" style="width:99vw; height: 99vh"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.bundle.js" integrity="sha512-zO8oeHCxetPn1Hd9PdDleg5Tw1bAaP0YmNvPY8CwcRyUk7d7/+nyElmFrB6f7vg4f7Fv4sui1mcep8RIEShczg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cjub5mhL/)